# Optimize Depth First Search in python - Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, depth-first-search

I have a directory through which I traverse recursively using below function.

```
for _item in _depth_first_traverse(start_folder):
    yield _item

def _depth_first_traverse(folderobj):
    #listcontents is method of folderobj class which return folder or file obj at immediate first level
    for _item in folderobj.listContents():
        yield _item
        # If the item is folder do recursive listing inside that folder
        if _item.isFolder:
            try:
                for _depth_item in _depth_first_traverse(_item):
                    yield _depth_item
            except Exception as e:
                pass
    return
```

Above function works fine and it yields the file or folder obj. However, when the directory has large number of files and folders, the computation is very slow.

Hence, I want to refactor the code to either use multiprocessing module to perform recursive listing of each folder in parallel and yield. Need to know how to implement this or any other solution to make this block execute fast are welcome.

Comment: On a typical computer, disc access is many times slower than CU speed. Therefore, the speed of your program is likely limited by disc speed and not by the CPU speed (in technical terms, it's [I/O-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound), not [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound)). For this reason, I'm pessimistic that using more threads will give you a big performance increase. Multi-threading is great for CPU-bound problems. For I/O-bound problems, adding more threads (i.e. running the code on multiple CPU cores) will not magically make the disc faster.